# Using gpkg layer as input in rasterize with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I try to rasterize a gpkg layer but it does not work efficiently. It always return empty raster data. However, if I run it by using processing toolbox it works. To see the code, I look the processing history and it gives me that:

```
processing.run("gdal:rasterize", {'INPUT':'D:/6/6.gpkg
layername=Nehir_Hidrojeolojik','FIELD':'fid','BURN':0,'UNITS':1,'WIDTH':524.3125958528195,'HEIGHT':904.5392875018064,'EXTENT':'590591.444106,601077.696023,4725233.720396,4743324.506146','NODATA':0,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':5,'INIT':0,'INVERT':False,'OUTPUT':'D:/deneme shp/2.tif'})
```

However, as you see, after `'INPUT':'D:/6/6.gpkg` it passes the new line and begin with `layername=Nehir_Hidrojeolojik'`. As you guess, it does not work in python console when I use it directly.

So I try to add `|` between `'INPUT':'D:/6/6.gpkg`and `'layername=Nehir_Hidrojeolojik'` something like that:

```
processing.run("gdal:rasterize", {'INPUT':'D:/6/6.gpkg|layername=Nehir_Hidrojeolojik','FIELD':'fid','BURN':0,'UNITS':1,'WIDTH':524.3125958528195,'HEIGHT':904.5392875018064,'EXTENT':'590591.444106,601077.696023,4725233.720396,4743324.506146','NODATA':0,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':5,'INIT':0,'INVERT':False,'OUTPUT':'D:/deneme shp/2.tif'})
```

But it does not work again. Is there anybody who have an idea about that?